# Referring to multiple string resources

Tags: android, android-resources

Is there a way to refer to multiple resources inside another?  It's easier to just show some sample code.

```
<resources>
   <string name="app_name">AppName</string>
   <string name="sep">--</string>
   <string name="action">MyAction</string>

   <string name="action_title">@string/app_name @string/sep @string/action</string>
</resources>
```

So that `@string/action_title` should be `AppName -- MyAction`

However, when I use this it seems that `R.java` just chokes and doesn't get built.  Am I missing something or is this just impossible?

**Edit**  I am using this to label `BroadcastReceivers` in my `AndroidManifest.xml` so doing it in code doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: As you just want to label broadcastreceiver that wil only be used once. So Just write the whole string there

Comment: It is for labeling about 3 receivers which need different separators for different api levels and different translations for action.  I was hoping to define the terms once and the separators once instead of repeating them for every variation.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible as long as you are using a single reference like

```
   <string name="app_name">AppName</string>
   <string name="sep">@string/AppName</string>
```

But you can not do multiple reference like you wanted nor like following

```
   <string name="app_name">AppName</string>
   <string name="sep">@string/AppName  --</string>
```

You can do that from code

```
   String s = getString(R.string.app_name) + " --";
```

Comment: Thanks, but via code isn't really an option.  This is for labeling broadcast receivers.

Comment: But multiple referencing is not possible . Tell me where you want to implement this?